# How to create static and dynamic library in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

How to create dynamic and static library in Makefile. I have C codes. In inc folder there is all of header files included and outside of this folder C files included. I want to create .a and .so library.How do i include wildcard which illustrates all the files will be executed.
I tried this way.

```
CFLAGS := -fPIC -O3 -g -Wall -Werror
CC := gcc
MAJOR := 0
MINOR := 1
NAME := foo
VERSION := $(MAJOR).$(MINOR)

lib: lib$(NAME).so

lib$(NAME).so.$(VERSION): $(NAME).o
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,lib$(NAME).so.$(MAJOR) $^ -o $(wildcard %.c)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.so*
```

Comment: the posted makefile will only produce a .so library.   You need add a first target, similar to: `all: lib$(NAME).so.$(VERSION)  lib$(NAME).a.$(VERSION)`   then write an additional recipe to produce the static library (lib$(NAME).a.$(VERSION)

Answer (score 3):

```
CFLAGS := -fPIC -O3 -g -Wall -Werror
CC := gcc
MAJOR := 0
MINOR := 1
NAME := foo
VERSION := $(MAJOR).$(MINOR)

LIBSO  = lib$(NAME).so
LIBSOM = $(LIBSO).$(MAJOR)
LIBSOV = $(LIBSO).$(VERSION)
LIBA   = lib$(NAME).a

lib: $(LIBSO) $(LIBA)

$(LIBSO): $(LIBSOV)
     ln -s $(LIBSOV) $(LIBSO)

$(LIBSOV): $(NAME).o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(LIBSOM) -o $(LIBSOV) $(NAME).o

$(LIBA): $(NAME).o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIBA) $(NAME).o

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.so*
```

Check to make sure that macros `AR` and `ARFLAGS` are set appropriately (`ar` and `ru` or thereabouts — I usually use `ruv`).

I'm not clear why you have a single object file `foo.o`, or whether in fact you wanted every C source file in the directory compiled into an object file and included in the library — your linking command for the shared object was not well-formed (it would have overwritten the first `.c` file as the shared object it created).

If you want more object files in the libraries, then define:

```
SOURCE := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECT := $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
```

and use `$(OBJECT)` in place of `$(NAME).o` in the rules.  Personally, I don't trust wildcards — there's too much danger of test program code etc being included in the library for my comfort.  YMMV.